# I want to create RDS instance using terraform in iteration

Tags: automation, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create RDS instances using terraform. I'm able to create one instance or multiple instances when I run terraform apply. But I want when I run terraform apply for the first time then it launches one rds instance and then if I again run terraform apply then it launches one more rds instance, and so on.

Below are my configuration files:

**vars.tf**

```
variable "engine" {}
variable "engine_version" {}
variable "instance_class" {}
variable "db_name" {}
variable "username" {}
variable "password" {}
variable "parameter_group_name" {}
variable "skip_final_snapshot" {}
variable "publicly_accessible" {}
variable "vpc_security_group_ids" {}
#variable "instance_settings" {}
variable "identifier" {
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}
variable "instance_count" {
  type    = number
  default = 1
}
```

**terraform.tfvars**

```
engine               = "postgres"
engine_version       = "14"
instance_class       = "db.t3.micro"
#instance_count       = 1
db_name              = "dbtfcreated"
username             = "postgres"
password             = "**********************"
identifier           = "database-1"
parameter_group_name = "manualparametergroup"
skip_final_snapshot  = true
publicly_accessible  = true
vpc_security_group_ids = ["sg-0514e829a818a8494"]
```

**below is my main.tf file **

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.0"
    }
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "tf" {
# Allocating the storage for database instance.
  allocated_storage    = 10
# RDS instance identifier name
  count      = var.instance_count
  #count                = length(aws_db_instance.tf) + 1
  identifier           = "${var.identifier}-${count.index + 1}"
# Declaring the database engine and engine_version
  engine               = var.engine
  engine_version       = var.engine_version
# Declaring the instance class
  instance_class       = var.instance_class
  db_name              = var.db_name
# User to connect the database instance
  username             = var.username
# Password to connect the database instance
  password             = var.password
  parameter_group_name = var.parameter_group_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.vpc_security_group_ids
  publicly_accessible = var.publicly_accessible
  skip_final_snapshot = var.skip_final_snapshot
}
```

It's creating one rds instance when I run terraform apply for the first time, but if I run it again then it says no change in your infra and it existed.

Also if I change instance count in the vars.tf file to 4 then it will launch 4 rds instances when I run terraform apply.

Comment: Simply put, that isn't how it works. Terraform is a stateful tool. You say you want one, you get one. No matter how many times you run it. What you need is a new state, or to add one to the count when you want to actually add another.

Comment: Can you please help how can make it to launch new instance each time i run and i don't want to increase count manually can u suggest something to make it dynamic

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is possibly not a good use for terraform or I may misunderstand. With terraform, you want to continue to manage a set of resources. If you want to just continue firing up new resources, you can just call the AWS API directly.

Imagine if you want to change the parameter group associated with these databases. With terraform, you can modify that parameter, then all databases managed at state address `aws_db_instance.tf` can be changed at once.

Simply running again will not add resources, because you have configured a [count](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/meta-arguments/count) and it is doing precisely what you told it too.

---

Now, having said all that for clarification, let's assume it actually is as dynamic as you want it to be, and you just haven't found the correct permutation yet. Consider this terraform definition.

```
variable "num_things" {
  type    = number
  default = 1
}

resource "null_resource" "this" {
  count = var.num_things
}

output "things" {
  value = null_resource.this
}

output "current_num_things" {
  value = length(null_resource.this)
}
```

Now, on the first run I get:

```
terraform apply
```

```
current_num_things = 1
things = [
  "c3f08f11-28ba-4174-0c9c-c3f1f1c8c95a",
]
```

And after the second, the same result, as you've witnessed. But, this is a variable, so we can increase it on the fly.

```
terraform apply -var num_things=2
```

```
current_num_things = 2
things = [
  "c3f08f11-28ba-4174-0c9c-c3f1f1c8c95a",
  "26d6f5a5-0ba9-723d-5d5d-8c43f75c74cf",
]
```

Okay, now what you want is for this to go up each time, but what I'm suggesting is that you don't want to lose state. So, you really just need to (outside terraform) set this var to the sum of the previous count and the number you want to add.

For example, you have 2 currently as above. We want 3 more.

```
terraform apply -var num_things=$(($(terraform output current_num_things) + 3))
```

And Bob's your uncle!

```
current_num_things = 5
things = [
  "c3f08f11-28ba-4174-0c9c-c3f1f1c8c95a",
  "26d6f5a5-0ba9-723d-5d5d-8c43f75c74cf",
  "0f0e495c-b5a9-17fc-7269-9ef4b79aa86b",
  "afcdd079-96ee-b947-63d9-3bf577fb9285",
  "5d95d6c5-e4ae-81c5-62fa-529b76dee9de",
]
```

Worth noting, if you run without count, it will want to delete the value of `current_num_things - 1`, the default. So you must always pass at least the value of `current_num_things`.

```
terraform apply -var num_things=$(terraform output current_num_things)
```